# Custom Class Function not working on Scene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So I'm experimenting with creating customized classes then using their functions but I can't even do the simplest of things.

This is my customized Class:

```
import SpriteKit

class BlockScene: SKScene {

    func createBlock(){ 
        print("Block Created")
    }
}
```

This is the code in my MainScene

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let variable = BlockScene(fileNamed: "Block")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        variable?.createBlock()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

When the main scene is loaded it does not execute my function createBlock(). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that the didMoveToView function is being called?

Comment: Yes I am because I tried a print() in the didMoveToView function and it printed to console @Carter

Comment: @Charles The thing is that you are going in a wrong way.  To create a sprite you only need to create an instance method on a current scene , or even static method on the GameScene which will create and return a new sprite. That variable called *variable* is not needed if its only purpose is to provide a method which creates a specific sprite.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Running this myself, it looks like you have no file named "Block" that you area loading from. When a `SKScene` initializes using the `fileNamed` method, it returns an optional, in the case that the file doesn't exist. In this case, "Block" doesn't exist, so variable is null, and will not call `createBlock()` in your `didMoveToView()` method.

**Solution**

You can either create the "Block" file that you need, or just call the default initializer for BlockScene, as below:

```
import SpriteKit

class BlockScene: SKScene {

    func createBlock(){
        print("Block Created")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let variable: BlockScene = BlockScene()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.variable.createBlock()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP has no clue as to what he is doing,  I would also point out that the block file should be a Sprite Kit Scene file called Block.sks